# Rest fb - authorization url to get page access token

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, javafx, restfb

I need to authenticate user's page from my Gui App. I didnt find any solution for me how to do it with java and restfb library. I am able to authenticate user from my Gui App, but i want to access user's page, not user's wall.

```
String domain = "http://seznam.cz/";
String appId = "1784741508503328";
String authUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent&client_id="+appId+"&redirect_uri="+domain+"&scope=user_about_me,"
      + "user_actions.books,user_actions.fitness,user_actions.music,user_actions.news,user_actions.video,user_birthday,user_education_history,"
      + "user_events,user_photos,user_friends,user_games_activity,user_hometown,user_likes,user_location,user_photos,user_relationship_details,"
      + "user_relationships,user_religion_politics,user_status,user_tagged_places,user_videos,user_website,user_work_history,ads_management,ads_read,email,"
      + "manage_pages,publish_actions,read_insights,user_friends,read_page_mailboxes,rsvp_event";
```

This code works only for user's wall/photos...etc But not for user's page. Could you please help me how to edit this url to get page access token? Thanks a lot.

Whole code:

```
public void getAccessToken(){
        String domain = "http://seznam.cz/";
        String appId = "1784741508503328";
        String authUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent&client_id="+appId+"&redirect_uri="+domain+"&scope=user_about_me,"
             + "user_actions.books,user_actions.fitness,user_actions.music,user_actions.news,user_actions.video,user_birthday,user_education_history,"
             + "user_events,user_photos,user_friends,user_games_activity,user_hometown,user_likes,user_location,user_photos,user_relationship_details,"
             + "user_relationships,user_religion_politics,user_status,user_tagged_places,user_videos,user_website,user_work_history,ads_management,ads_read,email,"
             + "manage_pages,publish_actions,read_insights,user_friends,read_page_mailboxes,rsvp_event";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(authUrl);
        while(true){
            if(!driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("facebook.com")){
                String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
                accessToken = url.replaceAll(".*#access_token=(.+)&.*", "$1");
                PrintWriter p = null;
                try {p = new PrintWriter("users.txt");} 
                catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}
                fbClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken);
                if(!accessToken.equals("null")){
                    p.println(extendToken().getAccessToken() + "," + extendToken().getExpires());
                }

                else{
                    p.print("");
                }
                driver.quit();
                p.close();
                return;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: This "code" ? It's only String, it does nothing

Comment: You don’t get a page access token via this URL. You need to request the necessary permission, and then make an API request to get the access tokens for the user’s pages. The documentation is really quite clear on how that works.

Comment: Of course that code does nothing. Its only part of code but the most key part. See edit

Comment: As soon as you have the user access token you simply have to call the me/accounts resource. You get a list of pages the user manages including their page access tokens. With RestFB this is a simple `fetchConnection`.

Comment: This way? Connection<Account> result2 = fbClient.fetchConnection("me/accounts",Account.class);

Comment: I've got it! Thanks a lot Norbert.

Answer (score -1):

It was easy as:

```
Connection<Account> result2 = fbClient.fetchConnection("me/accounts",Account.class);
for(List<Account> page : result2){   
      for(Account a : page){
            System.out.println(a.getAccessToken()); 
            System.out.println(a.getName());
      }
}
```

This code will print out all the pages names and their access tokens. You can simply store them in String and later use them.